# Cannot Resolve .process in Apache Camel Route

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I'm trying to expose a REST endpoint using Apache Camel. I'm trying to introduce use a processor to handle the management of the incoming messages however when I try and use `.process()`, IntelliJ complains that the method cannot be resolved.

My code looks like this:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

    restConfiguration()
          .host(host).port(port);

    rest("/exampleCallback").description("ExampleCallBackUri")
          .get()
          .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)
          .param().name(abc).type(RestParamType.query).required(true).endParam()
          .param().name(xyz).type(RestParamType.query).required(true).endParam() 
          .produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
          .process(messageProcessor).id("MessageProcessor")
          .to(exampleEndpoint);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it like this,

```
rest("/exampleCallback").description("ExampleCallBackUri")
          .get()
          .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)
          .param().name(abc).type(RestParamType.query).required(true).endParam()
          .param().name(xyz).type(RestParamType.query).required(true).endParam() 
          .produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
          .toD("someIntermediateEndpoint");

from("someIntermediateEndpoint")
          .process(messageProcessor).id("MessageProcessor")
          .to(exampleEndpoint);
```

Because `RestDefinition` doesn't have `process` method.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply :)